# IOS Add Hours to datepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In IOS Here I want to add either 2 or three hours in the date,Here I have tried but i didnt get correct result,Could anybody help me please.

```
NSDate *mydate = birthDatePicker.date;
    NSTimeInterval secondsInEightHours = 2 * 60 * 60;
    NSDate *dateEightHoursAhead = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];
    NSLog(@"dateEightHoursAhead %@",dateEightHoursAhead);
```

Comment: i think you wanna time interval is either 2 or 3 hr.Am i right ?

Comment: As I checked your code is working fine at my end. I am able to add 2 hours to mydate.

Comment: @dineshprasanna:show me your result?

Comment: Result is:CurrentHours 2013-04-16 18:22:32 +0000
AddedHours 2013-04-16 20:22:32 +0000 sorry sir, i got a result.Above solution is correct,but i saw it wrongly

Answer (score 0):

use this code for date picker

```
- (IBAction)dobbtn:(id)sender {


    UIActionSheet *dateActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    [dateActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [dateActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [dateActionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 383)];

    UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 100, 116)];


    dp.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [ dp addTarget: self action:
     @selector(dateChanged:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged
     ];


    [ self.view addSubview: dp ];

    txtDob.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 22.0 ];
    txtDob.textColor = [ UIColor blueColor ];

    txtDob.text = [ dp.date description ];

    [dp setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];


    [dateActionSheet addSubview:dp];

}



-(void) dateChanged: (id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *control = (UIDatePicker *) sender;
    NSDate *selectedDate = control.date;
    txtDob.text = [ selectedDate description ];
}
```